# Is the `rm` buildin GNU command case sensitive?

Tags: linux

Is there is a way to remove a file or directory ignoring if the name of the file is uppercase or lowercase?

Example. I both `/FiLe` and `/file`.

If I write: `rm /file` will it remove these two?

Comment: I wouldn't remove anything in linux starting with `/`

Answer (score 11):

Bad solution:

```
rm [Ff][Ii][Ll][Ee]
```

Better:

```
find . -iname "file" -exec rm {} \;
```

From *man*:

```
-iname pattern
       Like  -name, but the match is case insensitive.
```

Also, limit depth to only current directory; add `-maxdepth 1` before `iname`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "file" -exec rm {} \;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Careful though won't this remove all in the subdirectories?

Comment: Try `-maxdepth 1`. Thanks for remind, answer edited

Comment: @user2843739 - I'll be very thankful for check my answer as best :)

Comment: If you use `-exec rm {} ` then this will for a whole new process (rm) for **each file**.  You can use `-exec rm {} +` instead which will feed rm as many pathnames as possible for each invocation of utility. And there is always the option to use the build-in `-delete`.